# perform cumulative calculations based on certain columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe where I would like to perform cumulative calculations based on certain columns.
Needs to be grouped by id and date.

**Data**

```
id  date    pwr start   move
aa  q1 22   10  4       2
aa  q2 22   5   3       1
aa  q3 22   7   3       0
aa  q4 22   3   3       0
bb  q1 22   20  1       0
bb  q2 22   10  2       0
bb  q3 22   5   2       1
bb  q4 22   5   1       1
```

***Logic:***

final column values created by:

1. ‘start’ column - ‘move’column
2. ‘final’ column  - ‘pwr’ column - ‘move’ column

**Desired**

```
id  date    pwr start   move    final
aa  q1 22   10  4       2       2
aa  q2 22   5   3       1      -4
aa  q3 22   7   3       0      -11
aa  q4 22   3   3       0      -14
bb  q1 22   20  1       0       1
bb  q2 22   10  2       0      -9
bb  q3 22   5   2       1      -15
bb  q4 22   5   1       1      -21
```

**Doing**

```
df['final'] = df['start'].sub(df.groupby('id')['date'].cumsum())
df = df.assign(start = df['start'] - df['move'])
```

Performing cumsum grouping by id and date- however, the values in the final column are not calculating correctly. I am still troubleshooting this, any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Your logic is not very clear, it seems that you only have subtractions, can you better explain it? What are 1./2./3.?

Comment: 1.Start column - move column  2. Final column - pwr column - move column

Comment: can you break down how the "-4" in the second row is calculated?

Comment: Hi @Lynn. Can you check your output especially for group `bb`. I think you forget your first step. My output is `[2.0, -4.0, -11.0, -14.0, 1.0, -9.0, -13.0, -18.0]`

Comment: Let me check this

Comment: @Corralien I’m getting -9 - (5) = -14 then -1 = -15

Comment: And `start - move.cumsum()`?

Comment: @mozway ‘final’ 2 minus ‘start’ 3 minus ‘move’ 1

Comment: @Corralien I believe the final is what is doing the .cumsum

Comment: @Lynn btw, out of curiosity, what are those calculations? I see you often have similar situations with cumsums but all with a different setup.

Comment: It’s just a self project that I am doing to provide proper output calculations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
def f(x):
    final = x['start'].sub(x['move']).iloc[0]
    return x.shift(-1)[['pwr', 'move']].sum(axis=1).mul(-1) \
            .shift(fill_value=final).cumsum()

df['final'] = df.groupby('id').apply(f).astype(int).values
```

```
>>> df
   id   date  pwr  start  move  final
0  aa  q1 22   10      4     2      2
1  aa  q2 22    5      3     1     -4
2  aa  q3 22    7      3     0    -11
3  aa  q4 22    3      3     0    -14
4  bb  q1 22   20      1     0      1
5  bb  q2 22   10      2     0     -9
6  bb  q3 22    5      2     1    -15
7  bb  q4 22    5      1     1    -21
```

Comment: Hi @corralien -9 - 5 - 1 = -15 is what I am getting —- then -15 - 5 - 1 = -21

Comment: All the values are correct except the last two should be -15 and -21 I’m trying to tweak your code, thank you @corralien

Comment: -21 yes sorry for the typo there

Comment: Just explain me when I have to use `start - move.cumsum` (`a = ...`)

Comment: Ok then after you do start minus move, we get 2. Then we subtract 5 and subtract 1 which is -4. And same logic grouping by the Id. All the output is correct except last 2 values in final col

Comment: All the output is correct for `aa` because start minus move is [2, 0, 0, 0]. For `bb` start minus move is [1, 2, 1, -1]

Comment: Another question: What is the start minus move for `bb` please?

Comment: Ok yes but it is : start’ column - ‘move’column
‘final’ column - ‘pwr’ column - ‘move’ column

Comment: For bb it is start minus move which = 1 , then we subtract pwr (10) and subtract move which is 0 to get = -9

Comment: After -9, we then take this value, -9 and subtract 5 (‘pwr’) and 1 (‘move’) which gives = -15

Comment: I did it, I hope :)

Comment: Thank you could u tell me how the code works (the change you did) I’d like to educate myself on the changes

Comment: Will try this today

Comment: Shift all rows up and compute for each line, the value of `-1 * (pwr + move)`. Next shift all rows bottom and fill nan (the first row) by the `final` scalar value. Finally, you have just to `cumsum` each row with previous ones. I hope you will have understood my explanation because English is not my best skill :)

Comment: Hi @Corralien, on my full dataset, it is saying:  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'str'  when I perform: df['final'] = df.groupby('id').apply(f).astype(int).values  -  not sure why, as all the numerical values are floats and it shouldnt matter if the 'id' column is numerical or not

Comment: The problem is probably in  the function `f`. You have to check columns: `start`, `move` and `pwr`. Check dtype `df.info()`. One of this columns should be `object`.

Comment: Hi @Corralien, what If I wish to add start + move, would I need to change .sub to .sum?     final = x['start'].sub(x['move']).iloc[0]

Comment: Not `.sum` but `.add`.